# How to store pointer to redis list element in hash object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, data-structures, redis

I know you are not able to nest redis data structures. Let me explain a little of what I have designed:

I have a sorted set, where each element in the set is the key name to a FIFO redis List.

I also need a direct lookup to each element, which I want to store in a Hash. In the hash, I would like to be able to point directly to an element in a redis List.

Is this possible? Any ideas how to tweak this?

Comment: Store the integer of its position in the list maybe?

Comment: But the list can change, items can be deleted and updated.

Comment: Then maybe the other way round. Store the hashes key in the list?

Comment: Hmm, that's a possibility. By doing that, I could do direct lookups of the orders via the hash, while maintaining FIFO behavior via the list.

Comment: Because each hash key may have several objects in its value, I may have to generate a uuid of each value to store alongside the hash key in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Lists aren't suitable for random access (i.e. by index) - LRANGE is an expensive operation. Put differently, FIFO + random access it is **not** a job for a linked list.

Comment: If I take Jonas W.'s advice and store the data in a hash table, then store a uuid identifying each stored object in the list, then I can maintain the time-ordered properties of LIST, while having O(1) lookups. The only problem is deletion. If I delete an object from the hash table, I'll have to also store the key of the list name in the object, then do LRANGE to look for the element... Thankfully, I don't anticipate storing more than a dozen or so elements in a single list at any given time. However, I want it to be as efficient as possible, of course.

Comment: @MatthewDarnell if your list is at most a dozen-long, that shouldn't be a real problem despite slight inefficiency. O(N) is a PITA as N becomes larger.